Unable to import project as module in master android studio project
I build a simple Android Application. Now I need to import this project as MODULE in another android project.
So I do the following steps:
1 - File, New, Import Module
2 - Select the root of my Android project.
3 - Right click on app folder in Android studio, and click to Open module setting
4 - Select option Dependencies
5 - Click on APP and click on + button, select add Module dependency

But I cannot find my previous imported module.

Application modules and library modules are different things, and AFAIK you cannot use an application module as a dependency.

So what can I do to make this?

It is not completely clear what "this" is. But, if there is code that you want to share, that code will need to be in a library module.

I can create a package in my Android Application and convert that package in a module library?
